# why did <span> work here when <p> didn't?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Cou](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8uYQ.png)ld you please explain to me why using empty  element displays "Time Taken" and seconds it took. While if I use `"<p id="timer">Time Taken:</p>" and no <span>` it doesn't display the string "Time Taken"

[image: display without "Time Taken"] only the seconds it took is displayed. Thanks!

> **Time Taken:**
>
> ```
>     <script type="text/javascript">
>         var startTime = new Date().getTime();
>
>         function shapeAppear() { 
>
>             document.getElementById("square").style.display = "block"; 
>
>             startTime = new Date().getTime(); 
>
>         }
>
>         function shapeAppearDelay(){
>
>             setTimeout(shapeAppear, Math.random() * 2000);
>
>         }
>
>             shapeAppearDelay ();  
>
>             document.getElementById("square").onclick = function ()
>                {document.getElementById("square").style.display = "none"; 
>
>                var endTime = new Date().getTime(); 
>
>               var timeTaken = (endTime - startTime)/(1000)%60; 
>             //(1000)%60 to get seconds in minutes.  
>
>             document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = timeTaken; 
>
>         shapeAppearDelay ();                                                            
>         }
> ```

Comment: can you please add your HTML too?

Comment: I'm not seeing the string "Time Taken" in your code.

Comment: I would strongly suggest closing this question, and then reading the "*[ask]*," and "*[mcve]*," guidelines. As written it's difficult for me to work out what you want us to help with, and without your HTML (and perhaps even CSS) it's almost incomprehensible.

Comment: It does not show the text because you replace the HTML of the element....

Comment: I did include the html not sure why not showing. Here it is:  <body>
            
            <p><b>Time Taken: </b><span id="timer"></span> </p>
           <div id="square"></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are completely changing contents of your #timer with this line:

```
document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = timeTaken;
```

To only append to the end of element, use this code:

```
var element = document.getElementById("timer");
element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML + timeTaken;
```